# TableView with scroll and swipe

Tags: javascript, iphone, titanium

I have a TableView in which I can scroll to view all the rows.
But I can also swipe all of those rows (when I swipe, it display some options for the row).

Currently, I'm adding a swipe event to the table view. When it's triggered, I find the appropriate row with it's index. And I do what I gotta do.
On the SDK it works well.

On a real machine though, it's very hard to get the row to swipe.
The scroll is always triggered.

I'm unfortunately afraid this could be a hardware problem and there wouldn't be anything I could do.

Comment: Why not catch the swipe in the cells directly? Not sure if it will help though. Depending on your minimum OS requirements, adding a UIGestureRecognizer for swipes would be sufficient. "Reeder" seems to implement something like what you ask - toggling read articles and marking them. Hmmm... not sure what you are using exactly, as your question is tagged javascript and titanium.

Comment: I'm using titanium. Not programming in Objective C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Eiko mentionned, I'm not programming my application in Objective-C. But with [Titanium Mobile](http://www.appcelerator.com/).

His advice was right though. By setting the event in the row instead of the table, it works find :)